# Implementing Stack get method

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I've created my own Stack class but need to implement a get method to return a stack element based on an index passed within the args.  I've created a contains method and would of assumed get would work in a similar fashion.

My question is how would I implement the get method? I want to basically implement the get method that Stack inherits from the Vector class in the standard library.  See -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29

Here is my contains method below.

```
public boolean contains (T value){

    T t = top.item; 
    Object node = t;
    while(node!=null)
    {
        if(node==value){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            node=top.next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what is the question and yes it will work the same way?

Comment: What does that index argument do? Specify the depth into the stack? Counted from the top? Either way, that's an unusual Stack. Normally, you can just push/pop/peek.

Comment: I want to basically implement the get method that Stack inherits from Vector class.  See -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29

Comment: As a side note if this code were in my team's API it would be deprecated immediately.

Comment: If you add `get()` to a stack, you've made it a list.

Answer (score 1):

The classical Stack does not support that operation, and truly should not extend Vector.

The operations that it supports are:

```
push(item)  
pop();  
peek();
```

So what you want to do, if you want to use a data structure to back your Stack is to use an instance of a List which will allow you to mirror what the original Sun team did.

```
 function contains(Item item)  
 {  
     return Stack.getList().contains(item)  
 }
```

If instead you want to just use an array as the backing you would need to iterate over each value in the array and perform an equals comparison on it.

```
function contains(Item item)  
{  
   for(int i = 0; i < itemArray.length;i++)  
   {  
      if(itemArray[i] == item)   
      {   
           return true;    
      }
   }
      return false;
}
```